# What's the template code to display error/success messages?

Tags: magento2

I want flash messages to appear on a custom page I am making. Since I am removing pretty much all of the other layout, I need to find the templating code that prints out messages.

If I already have the desired messages, dow do I display them? Where is the template code for actually displaying the messages?

Comment: you can call it by using a function in your block with message manager

Answer (score 1):

this seems to work:

```
<?php include ($block->getTemplateFile('Magento_Theme::messages.phtml')) ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is located here - `magento2ce/app/code/Magento/Theme/view/frontend/templates/messages.phtml`

The messages are loaded using ajax calls and rendered using JS. Thus, you only need to add block to your layout like following:

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="ajax.message.placeholder" template="Magento_Theme::html/messages.phtml"/>
```

Comment: to which xml this code should be added?